# Trace of non-commutable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, traces

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two symmetric $d\times d$ matrices. What is the relationship between
$tr(M_1M_2M_1M_2)$ and $tr(M_1^2 M_2^2 )$?

P.S. I tried a few examples and found
$$
tr(M_1M_2M_1M_2) \le tr(M_1^2 M_2^2 )
$$
seems always true. Is there a theorem?

Comment: No there isn't. Try matrix units $M_1 = E_{12}, M_2 = E_{21} \in \mathbb M_2$. Then the LHS is 1 and the RHS is 0.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I should have added symmetric condition! I corrected the statement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your conjecture is a special case of the following result which essentially follows from the Lieb-Thirring inequality.

Let $A$ and $B$ be Hermitian matrices. Then, for every positive integer $p$ we have 
\begin{equation*}
 |\text{tr}(AB)^{2p}| \le \text{tr}A^{2p}B^{2p}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Wikipedia insists that something like this be called [Araki–Lieb–Thirring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequalities#Araki-Lieb-Thirring_inequality), not just [Lieb–Thirring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lieb–Thirring_inequality).  Its result by the latter name seems unrelated, and its result by the former name requires that the matrices be positive definite, as well as considering $B A B$ in place of $A B$.  Is there some other version that drops these differences?

Comment: So the proof is $tr(ABAB) = tr( (A^{1/2} B A^{1/2})^2) \leq tr(A^{1/2} B A^{1/2})^2 = tr(AB)^2 \overset{ALT}{\leq} tr(A^2 B^2)$, yes?

Comment: @LSpice Araki proved a more general inequality (see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01045887); here the simpler Lieb-Thirring result from 1976 suffices.

Comment: @JohannesHahn why the additional inequality (prior to LT); isn't $ABAB=(AB)^2$ :-)

Comment: "Lieb-Thirring inequality" normally means: bound the $\ell^p$ norm of the negative eigenvalues of a Schrodinger operator by the $L^q$ norm of the potential, though it's very possible of course that they proved the matrix inequality above somewhere in these works.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I'm just using the version apparent from Araki's paper, who cites Lieb-Thirring as having proved the simpler inequality. But I agree, outside of matrix inequality land, dropping Araki's name may confuse some.

Comment: @JohannesHahn, doesn't that require some kind of positive definiteness to take the square roots?

Answer (score 10):

Not to take anything away from Suvrit's answer, but this is actually much simpler. First, we can assume $M_1$ is diagonal. Call it $diag(x_1, \dotsc, x_i).$
Then the difference between the LHS and the RHS is

$$\sum_{i> j} a_{ij}^2 (x_i - x_j)^2,$$
where the $a_{ij}$ are the entries of $M_2.$

Comment: So it seems we only need to assume one of them is symmetric.

Comment: Another proof is $0 \leq \text{tr}[A, B]^{t}[A, B] = 2\text{tr}(A^{2}B^{2}) - 2\text{tr}(ABAB)$, for symmetric $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Koltchinskii I was assuming both of them were symmetric...